# A command to move forward to a specific (numbered) column?

Tags: tables

Suppose I want a `\gotocolumn` command, with the following behavior: in a tabular with n or more columns, `\gotocolumn{n}` would expand to the shortest combination of `\\` and `&` necessary to bring us forward into the n'th column.  So for instance...

- In the first column of a table, `\gotocolumn{3}` would expand to `& &`.
- In the second column of a table, `\gotocolumn{3}` would expand to `&`.
- In the third column of a table, `\gotocolumn{3}` would expand to `\relax`.
- In the fourth or subsequent column of a table, `\gotocolumn{3}` would expand to `\\ & &`.

Has this been done?  Could it be done?  Thoughts on how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some bookkeeping when new columns and rows are started. If you really want to you can redefine `&` and `\\` I chose to introduce some new macros that just "call" the normal ones and do some additional work. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{currCol}
\setcounter{currCol}{1}
\def\amp{\stepcounter{currCol}&}
\def\nl{\\\setcounter{currCol}{1}}
\newcounter{numCols}
\setcounter{numCols}{3}
\def\gotocolumn#1{%
  \ifnum\the\value{currCol}=#1%done
  \else%
    \ifnum\the\value{currCol}<#1% before same row
      \amp\gotocolumn{#1}%
    \else% after, next row
      \ifnum\the\value{currCol}<\the\value{numCols}% need additional columns
        \amp\gotocolumn{#1}%
      \else%
        \nl\gotocolumn{#1}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    test \amp test \amp test\nl
    more \amp test \amp stuff\nl
    \gotocolumn{2}test \amp test\nl
    \gotocolumn{3}last\nl
    first \amp \gotocolumn{1}first
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this.

[image: gotocolumn results]

It's not tested very well, so there might be some issues in border cases.

Comment: Does this mean that in a normal LaTeX tabular -- without redefining the tab/newline commands -- there's no way for a macro to "find out" where in the table it's being evaluated?

Comment: @DanVelleman: You could use [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to process each cell and keep track of the columns. That way the table would look like a normal table. This recent answer question on [customize the cell environment in a tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39046/customize-the-cell-environment-in-a-tabular/39047#39047) shows an example usage of `collcell`.

Comment: @DanVelleman not as far as I know. Depending on what you mean when you say "redefining the tab/newline commands". Because I'm pretty sure that's exactly what `collcell` does as well. You can of course redefine the ampersand and `\\` to make it look like any other table, while performing the same actions as `\amp` and `\nl`.