# Customize the "cell environment" in a tabular

Tags: tables

Is there a way to modify the layout of cells in a `tabular`?

I would like to have a environment mytable which I would use like a `tabular`:

```
\begin{mytable}{l|l}
entry & entry \\
entry & entry 
\end{mytable}
```

which would create a `tabular`, and such that for each entry, it would insert some 
`\mycommand` at the beginning of each cell.

Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at the `array` package documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I provides exactly what i need.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn: The `array` package allows for custom column types, but don't think it provides any way to apply a macro to each cell of a table.  That is what `collcell` is for.

Comment: yes it does : So, the solution is indeed with the package array :
    \begin{tabular}{>{\mycommand}l|>{\mycommand}l}
    aaaa & bbbb\    cccc & dddd
    \end{tabular}
it works.

Comment: @PeterGrill The `>{}` `<{}` syntax of column specification in the `array` packages allows this.  There may be some cases for which `collcell` is necessary, but for most cases `array` is sufficient.  I've never used `collcell`, yet I have plenty of custom column types with macros applied.

Comment: Ok, I see the confusion on my part. You can use macros with the `newcolumtype` from the `array` pacakge, but I don't think you can access the cell contents so you can apply simple formatting commands only. For example, if you want to examine the cell contents as [in a tabular how to left align ignoring minus signs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34619/4301) you would need `collcel`. But if you the macro you want to apply does not need access to the cell contents then `array` would suffice.  I read the question assuming the more complex case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `collcell` package:

You can use [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to process an entry based on the column type. Below I have defined the `L` column type applied this to the first column which, in this example, changes the text color to red.

[image]

If you want to apply the same macro to each column use the `L` column type for that column. You can also define additional column types and apply different macros to cells in different columns.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\MyCommand}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L | l}
entry & entry \\
entry & entry 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

### `array` package:

If you want to apply a macro that does not need access to the cell contents you can simply use [the `array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and don't need `collcell`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L | l}
entry & entry \\
entry & entry 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

### Macro To Process Each Row:

Alternatively, if you want you could add a macro for each row and apply the particular commands within that macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\MyCommand}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1}&\textcolor{blue}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l | l}
\MyCommand{entry}{entry} \\
\MyCommand{entry}{entry} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps, if the OP has a fixed structure (like in the original question; a 2x2 matrix), you could also provide, as an alternative, a macro that takes 4 arguments and formats them accordingly. It would be very specific, but it may appeal to the OP.

Comment: @Werner: I did not read the question that way since the OP specifically states "insert some at the beginning of each cell". Form this I assume he wants cell by cell processing, not row by row processing.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution assumes two things:

1. a fixed 2x2 matrix structure; and
2. you want to apply the same command to all the entries.

The following MWE provides `\mymatrix[<col spec>]{<tl>}{<tr>}{<bl>}{<br>}` that places the four mandatory arguments in a left-to-right, top-down (or row-by-row) fashion in a 2x2 `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{​\mymatrix}[5][l|l]{% \mymatrix[<col spec>]{<tl>}{<tr>}{<bl>}{<br>}
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \MyCommand{#2} & \MyCommand{#3} \\ \MyCommand{#4} & \MyCommand{#5}
  \end{tabular}
​}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{#1}% \MyCommand{<stuff>} just prints <stuff> untouched
\mymatrix{a}{b}{c}{d}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}% \MyCommand{<stuff>} prints <stuff> in red
\mymatrix{a}{b}{c}{d}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{\textcolor{blue!50}{\textsf{#1}}}% \MyCommand{<stuff>} prints <stuff> in 50% blue and serif font
\mymatrix[|p{2in}|l|]{a}{b}{c}{d}% Also changed the column specification
\end{document}
​
```

The optional command to `\mymatrix[<col-spec>]` allows you to (re)specify the `tabular` column specification, which defaults to `l|l`. The last command utilizes this modification.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but i don't want to fix the size of the array in advance.