# Create Custom tabular

Tags: tables, environments

Is there a way to make something like tabular such that in a loop we get each column in a line and render them in a custom format. Like this

```
\begin{custom_tabular}
l1c1 & l1c2 & l1c3 \\
l2c1 & l2c2 & l2c3
\end{custom_tabular}
```

and render the the elements in a custom format, e.g.

```
\textbf{l1c1}: l1c2$^{l1c3}$
```

for all the lines. Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) which allows you to pass the entry of each column to a command for further processing:

[image]

Below I have defined two new column types. The `H` column type is for the header column, and the `E` column type is for the exponent column.  The middle column is just a normal `l`, but with a `@{}` to remove the column separation between this column and the subsequent column containing the exponent.

### References:

A previous answer of mine [customize the “cell environment” in a tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39046/customize-the-cell-environment-in-a-tabular/39047#39047) also shows:

- How to use [the `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), which can definitely accommodate the header column with

  ```
    \newcolumntype{H}{>{\bfseries}l<{:}}%
  ```

  but not sure how to get the superscript column to work.
- A method which does not require any additional packages, by defining a macro to process each row. But, this requires changing each row of the table.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\HeaderColumn}[1]{\textbf{#1:}}
\newcommand{\ExponentColumn}[1]{${}^{#1}$}%

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\HeaderColumn}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ExponentColumn}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{H l@{} E}
    l1c1 & l1c2 & l1c3 \\
    l2c1 & l2c2 & l2c3
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `\halign` TeX primitive does.

```
\halign{{\bf#\unskip}: &#\unskip&$^{#}$\cr
l1c1 & l1c2 & l1c3 \cr
l2c1 & l2c2 & l2c3 \cr
}
```